# In detail, how does the 'for each' loop work in Java?

Tags: java, foreach, syntactic-sugar

Consider:

```java
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();
// add "monkey", "donkey", "skeleton key" to someList
```

```java
for (String item : someList) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

What would the equivalent `for` loop look like without using the *for each* syntax?

---

<sub>People new to Java commonly encounter issues when trying to *modify the original data* using the new style foreach loop. Use [Why doesn't assigning to the iteration variable in a foreach loop change the underlying data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844443) to close duplicates about that common problem. Note that other languages with analogous constructs generally have the same issue; for example, see [Why doesn't modifying the iteration variable affect subsequent iterations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363138) for the same issue in Python.</sub>

Comment: As per JLS it has two forms: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33232565/1216775

Answer (score 1310, accepted):

```
for (Iterator<String> i = someIterable.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    String item = i.next();
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Note that if you need to use `i.remove();` in your loop, or access the actual iterator in some way, you cannot use the `for ( : )` idiom, since the actual iterator is merely inferred.

As was noted by Denis Bueno, this code works for any object that implements the [`Iterable` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

If the right-hand side of the `for (:)` idiom is an array rather than an `Iterable` object, the internal code uses an int index counter and checks against `array.length` instead. See the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).

```java
for (int i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    String item = someArray[i];
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Answer (score 560):

The construct *for each* is also valid for arrays. e.g.

```
String[] fruits = new String[] { "Orange", "Apple", "Pear", "Strawberry" };

for (String fruit : fruits) {
    // fruit is an element of the `fruits` array.
}
```

which is essentially equivalent of

```
for (int i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    String fruit = fruits[i];
    // fruit is an element of the `fruits` array.
}
```

So, overall summary: 
[[nsayer]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work/85206#85206) The following is the longer form of what is happening:

> ```
> for(Iterator<String> i = someList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
>   String item = i.next();
>   System.out.println(item);
> }
> ```
>
> Note that if you need to use
>   i.remove(); in your loop, or access
>   the actual iterator in some way, you
>   cannot use the for( : ) idiom, since
>   the actual Iterator is merely
>   inferred.

[[Denis Bueno]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work/85242#85242)

> It's implied by nsayer's answer, but
>   it's worth noting that the OP's for(..)
>   syntax will work when "someList" is
>   anything that implements
>   java.lang.Iterable -- it doesn't have
>   to be a list, or some collection from
>   java.util. Even your own types,
>   therefore, can be used with this
>   syntax.

Comment: I wouldn't say the 2nd example is "essentially equivalent to the first", since if its a list of primitive values, any modification you make to the values will not modify the original list in example 1, but will modify the original list in example 2.

Comment: @Kosaro what kind of modifications are you talking about? In neither example does modifying the loop variable, i.e. `fruit`, affect the array.

Answer (score 197):

The [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html), added in [Java 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/index.html) (also called the "enhanced for loop"), is equivalent to using a [`java.util.Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)--it's syntactic sugar for the same thing. Therefore, when reading each element, one by one and in order, a for-each should always be chosen over an iterator, as it is more convenient and concise.

#### For-each

```
for (int i : intList) {
   System.out.println("An element in the list: " + i);
}
```

#### Iterator

```
Iterator<Integer> intItr = intList.iterator();
while (intItr.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println("An element in the list: " + intItr.next());
}
```

There are situations where you must use an `Iterator` directly. For example, attempting to delete an element while using a for-each can (will?) result in a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

### For-each vs. for-loop: Basic differences

The only practical difference between for-loop and for-each is that, in the case of indexable objects, you do not have access to the index. An example when the basic for-loop is required:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   if(i < 5) {
      // Do something special
   }  else {
      // Do other stuff
   }
}
```

Although you could manually create a separate index int-variable with for-each,

```
int idx = -1;
for (int i : intArray) {
   idx++;
   ...
}
```

...it is not recommended, since [variable-scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) is not ideal, and the basic `for` loop is simply the standard and expected format for this use case.

### For-each vs. for-loop: Performance

When accessing collections, a for-each is [significantly faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879255/traditional-for-loop-vs-iterator-in-java) than the basic `for` loop's array access. When accessing arrays, however--at least with primitive and wrapper-arrays--access via indexes is dramatically faster.

#### Timing the difference between iterator and index access for primitive int-arrays

Indexes are 23-*40* percent faster than iterators when accessing `int` or `Integer` arrays. Here is the output from the testing class at the bottom of this post, which sums the numbers in a 100-element primitive-int array (A is iterator, B is index):

```
[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntArray 1000000
Test A: 358,597,622 nanoseconds
Test B: 269,167,681 nanoseconds
B faster by 89,429,941 nanoseconds (24.438799231635727% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntArray 1000000
Test A: 377,461,823 nanoseconds
Test B: 278,694,271 nanoseconds
B faster by 98,767,552 nanoseconds (25.666236154695838% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntArray 1000000
Test A: 288,953,495 nanoseconds
Test B: 207,050,523 nanoseconds
B faster by 81,902,972 nanoseconds (27.844689860906513% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntArray 1000000
Test A: 375,373,765 nanoseconds
Test B: 283,813,875 nanoseconds
B faster by 91,559,890 nanoseconds (23.891659337194227% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntArray 1000000
Test A: 375,790,818 nanoseconds
Test B: 220,770,915 nanoseconds
B faster by 155,019,903 nanoseconds (40.75164734599769% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntArray 1000000
Test A: 326,373,762 nanoseconds
Test B: 202,555,566 nanoseconds
B faster by 123,818,196 nanoseconds (37.437545972215744% faster)
```

I also ran this for an `Integer` array, and indexes are still the clear winner, but only between 18 and 25 percent faster.

#### For collections, iterators are faster than indexes

For a `List` of `Integers`, however, iterators are the clear winner. Just change the int-array in the test-class to:

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100});
```

And make the necessary changes to the test-function (`int[]` to `List<Integer>`, `length` to `size()`, etc.):

```
[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntegerList 1000000
Test A: 3,429,929,976 nanoseconds
Test B: 5,262,782,488 nanoseconds
A faster by 1,832,852,512 nanoseconds (34.326681820485675% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntegerList 1000000
Test A: 2,907,391,427 nanoseconds
Test B: 3,957,718,459 nanoseconds
A faster by 1,050,327,032 nanoseconds (26.038700083921256% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntegerList 1000000
Test A: 2,566,004,688 nanoseconds
Test B: 4,221,746,521 nanoseconds
A faster by 1,655,741,833 nanoseconds (38.71935684115413% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntegerList 1000000
Test A: 2,770,945,276 nanoseconds
Test B: 3,829,077,158 nanoseconds
A faster by 1,058,131,882 nanoseconds (27.134122749113843% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntegerList 1000000
Test A: 3,467,474,055 nanoseconds
Test B: 5,183,149,104 nanoseconds
A faster by 1,715,675,049 nanoseconds (32.60101667104192% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntList 1000000
Test A: 3,439,983,933 nanoseconds
Test B: 3,509,530,312 nanoseconds
A faster by 69,546,379 nanoseconds (1.4816434912159906% faster)

[C:\java_code\]java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntList 1000000
Test A: 3,451,101,466 nanoseconds
Test B: 5,057,979,210 nanoseconds
A faster by 1,606,877,744 nanoseconds (31.269164666060377% faster)
```

In one test they're almost equivalent, but with collections, iterator wins.

*This post is based on two answers I wrote on Stack Overflow:

- *[Uses and syntax for for-each loop in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110482/uses-and-syntax-for-for-each-loop-in-java/22110517#22110517)*
- *[Should I use an Iterator or a forloop to iterate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540025/should-i-use-an-iterator-or-a-forloop-to-iterate/22540191#22540191)*

Some more information: *[Which is more efficient, a for-each loop, or an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113216/which-is-more-efficient-a-for-each-loop-or-an-iterator)*

#### The full testing class

I created this compare-the-time-it-takes-to-do-any-two-things class after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java) on Stack Overflow:

```
import  java.text.NumberFormat;
import  java.util.Locale;

/**
   &lt;P&gt;{@code java TimeIteratorVsIndexIntArray 1000000}&lt;/P&gt;

   @see  &lt;CODE&gt;&lt;A HREF=&quot;https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java&quot;&gt;https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java&lt;/A&gt;&lt;/CODE&gt;
 **/
public class TimeIteratorVsIndexIntArray {

    public static final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);

    public static final void main(String[] tryCount_inParamIdx0) {
        int testCount;

        // Get try-count from a command-line parameter
        try {
           testCount = Integer.parseInt(tryCount_inParamIdx0[0]);
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | NumberFormatException x) {
           throw  new IllegalArgumentException("Missing or invalid command line parameter: The number of testCount for each test. " + x);
        }

        //Test proper...START
        int[] intArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100};

        long lStart = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i = 0; i < testCount; i++) {
           testIterator(intArray);
        }

        long lADuration = outputGetNanoDuration("A", lStart);

        lStart = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i = 0; i < testCount; i++) {
           testFor(intArray);
        }

        long lBDuration = outputGetNanoDuration("B", lStart);

        outputGetABTestNanoDifference(lADuration, lBDuration, "A", "B");
    }

    private static final void testIterator(int[] int_array) {
       int total = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < int_array.length; i++) {
          total += int_array[i];
       }
    }

    private static final void testFor(int[] int_array) {
       int total = 0;
       for(int i : int_array) {
          total += i;
       }
    }
    //Test proper...END

    //Timer testing utilities...START
    public static final long outputGetNanoDuration(String s_testName, long l_nanoStart) {
        long lDuration = System.nanoTime() - l_nanoStart;
        System.out.println("Test " + s_testName + ": " + nf.format(lDuration) + " nanoseconds");
        return  lDuration;
    }

    public static final long outputGetABTestNanoDifference(long l_aDuration, long l_bDuration, String s_aTestName, String s_bTestName) {
        long lDiff = -1;
        double dPct = -1.0;
        String sFaster = null;
        if(l_aDuration > l_bDuration) {
            lDiff = l_aDuration - l_bDuration;
            dPct = 100.00 - (l_bDuration * 100.0 / l_aDuration + 0.5);
            sFaster = "B";
        }
        else {
            lDiff = l_bDuration - l_aDuration;
            dPct = 100.00 - (l_aDuration * 100.0 / l_bDuration + 0.5);
            sFaster = "A";
        }
        System.out.println(sFaster + " faster by " + nf.format(lDiff) + " nanoseconds (" + dPct + "% faster)");
        return  lDiff;
   }

   //Timer testing utilities...END

}
```

Comment: This answer is now a [blog post](http://aliteralmind.wordpress.com/2014/03/22/for_foreach/) and was created from two related answers that I've written: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540025/should-i-use-an-iterator-or-a-forloop-to-iterate/22540191#22540191) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110482/uses-and-syntax-for-for-each-loop-in-java/22110517#22110517). It also includes a generically useful class for comparing the speed of two functions (at the bottom).

Comment: Just one minor comment here, you shouldn't categorically state that for(:) syntax is always better for accessing collections; if you are using an array list, the for (:) loop will be about 2 x slower than using for (int i = 0, len = arrayList.size(); i < len; i++).  I think you mentioned that in the [link]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113216/which-is-more-efficient-a-for-each-loop-or-an-iterator) link anyway, but is important to highlight that...

Comment: @Leo It's a good point. An ArrayList is Collection, but it's backed by an array, which is why the normal for is better for it.

Comment: I imagine the `for(int value : int_array) {/* loop content */}` is slowest in your test because it is syntactically equivalent to `for(int i = 0; i < int_array.length; i++) {int value =  int_array[i]; /* loop content */}`, which isn't what your test compares.

Comment: (by the way, I'm not saying your test is invalid, but it might be worth noting the reasons behind the difference so that people can choose what is right for their particular scenario.  If they are doing a `int value = int_array[i];` at the start of their for loop, then they might as well use foreach.  Unless they need access to the index, too, for some reason.  In short, it all depends on context.)

Comment: It's important to compare apples-to-apples, here. The question was about `for` versus `foreach`. You are comparing indexed-access versus iterated access. It's important to point out that `foreach` is just syntactic sugar wrapping "iterator" traversal of the collection. There is no discernible difference between `for` and `foreach` when you are always using an iterator, so it's not fair to imply that `foreach` is better for performance. Technically speaking, it generates the same code as a regular `for` loop *provided that you are still using an iterator in the for loop*.

Comment: To me saying that foreach is more performant when going through Collection is terribly misleading. If it is a linked list in a for loop using the get(i), you're not traversing once, you're traversing 1+2+..n times. Using iterable is to make sure to go through the Collection in the most optimal way without having to have to write extra code (ex : current = current.getChild()). Of course for ArrayList, you will be a bit faster using a for instead fo foreach because you don't need to construct the intermediary Iterator. A logical explanation is way better than benchmarks in this case for me

Comment: Just stumbled upon this accidentally.. and I think on one point, which I didn't pay much attention before: if for-each is defined to be the syntactic sugar when iterating over `Iterable`s, how, or why does it work in case of primitive `int[]`? because, primitive array doesn't really override `Iterator();`.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri If I remember correctly, ints are automatically and quietly wrapped into Integers.

Comment: @aliteralmind Actually your benchmark doesn't warmup the VM correctly and doesn't compensate for GC runs. The results can't be trusted. Make sure to read how to use JMH for executing these types of tests
https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness

Comment: It was a good exercise, but I obviously didn’t know what the hell I was talking about.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri The compiler output of a for-each loop for an array is different than for an `Iterable`. It's actually two different cases of syntactic sugar designed to look consistent.

Comment: @aliteralmind Trying to compare performance of two small pieces of code is fraught with pitfalls. JVM warmup, memory loading and cache effects, compiler optimizations, the choice of collection to iterate over... In general, when the difference between two approaches must be measured in nanoseconds for one iteration and even with a million iterations the scale is still in seconds and not minutes, there's no point in worrying about the difference for 99.99% of your use cases. Go with what's most convenient. If it does matter, Java might be the wrong language for your purpose to begin with.

Comment: @G_H Sure. I wrote this seven years ago. It was an interesting experience and experiment, even if the primary goal wasn’t meaningful. No one should be writing a code-timer unless you know what you’re doing. I didn’t.

Answer (score 138):

Here is an answer which does not assume knowledge of Java Iterators. It is less precise, but it is useful for education.

While programming we often write code that looks like the following:

```
char[] grades = ....
for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {   // for i goes from 0 to grades.length
    System.out.print(grades[i]);           // Print grades[i]
}
```

The foreach syntax allows this common pattern to be written in a more natural and less syntactically noisy way.

```
for(char grade : grades) {   // foreach grade in grades
    System.out.print(grade); // print that grade
}
```

Additionally this syntax is valid for objects such as Lists or Sets which do not support array indexing, but which do implement the Java Iterable interface.

Answer (score 49):

The for-each loop in Java uses the underlying iterator mechanism. So it's identical to the following:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = someList.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  String item = iterator.next();
  System.out.println(item);
}
```

Comment: This is what people actually used before for-each, not the C-style for statement.

Answer (score 49):

As defined in [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), a *for-each* loop can have two forms:

1. If the type of expression is a subtype of `Iterable` then translation is as:

   ```
   List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
   someList.add("Apple");
   someList.add("Ball");
   for (String item : someList) {
       System.out.println(item);
   }

   // Is translated to:

   for(Iterator<String> stringIterator = someList.iterator(); stringIterator.hasNext(); ) {
       String item = stringIterator.next();
       System.out.println(item);
   }
   ```
2. If the expression necessarily has an array type `T[]` then:

   ```
   String[] someArray = new String[2];
   someArray[0] = "Apple";
   someArray[1] = "Ball";

   for(String item2 : someArray) {
       System.out.println(item2);
   }

   // Is translated to:
   for (int i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
       String item2 = someArray[i];
       System.out.println(item2);
   }
   ```

Java 8 has introduced streams which perform generally better with a decent size dataset. We can use them as:

```
someList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
Arrays.stream(someArray).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: The most relevant and accurate answer. Enchansed for has two translations indeed.

Comment: I entirely disagree with: *Java 8 has introduced streams which perform generally better.*, streams are only really feasible if you work with a big enough data set. Also `.stream().forEach()` can be replaced with `.forEach()`

Comment: I'm not so thinking about .forEach(), because the run times of forEeach more than for loop, so that's  forEarch don't best solutions

Answer (score 28):

It's implied by [nsayer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work/85206#85206), but it's worth noting that the OP's for(..) syntax will work when "someList" is *anything* that implements java.lang.Iterable -- it doesn't have to be a list, or some collection from java.util. Even your own types, therefore, can be used with this syntax.

Comment: fd is right - the internal code when the right-hand side of the for(:) idiom uses an int and array.length instead of fetching an Iterator. http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=2743233

Answer (score 26):

A foreach loop syntax is:

```
for (type obj:array) {...}
```

Example:

```
String[] s = {"Java", "Coffe", "Is", "Cool"};
for (String str:s /*s is the array*/) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Output:

```
Java
Coffe
Is
Cool
```

WARNING: You can access array elements with the foreach loop, but you can NOT initialize them. Use the original `for` loop for that.

WARNING: You must match the type of the array with the other object.

```
for (double b:s) // Invalid-double is not String
```

If you want to edit elements, use the original `for` loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length-1 /*-1 because of the 0 index */; i++) {
    if (i==1) //1 because once again I say the 0 index
        s[i]="2 is cool";
    else
        s[i] = "hello";
}
```

Now if we dump s to the console, we get:

```
hello
2 is cool
hello
hello
```

Answer (score 24):

The Java "for-each" loop construct will allow iteration over two types of objects:

- `T[]` *(arrays of any type)*
- `java.lang.Iterable<T>`

The `Iterable<T>` interface has only one method: `Iterator<T> iterator()`.  This works on objects of type `Collection<T>` because the `Collection<T>` interface extends `Iterable<T>`.

Answer (score 23):

In Java 8 features you can use this:

```
List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("First", "Second", "Third");

void forTest(){
    messages.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

#### Output

```
First
Second
Third
```

Comment: this random information doesn't even remotely answer the question

Answer (score 20):

The concept of a foreach loop as mentioned in Wikipedia is highlighted below:

> Unlike other for loop constructs, however, foreach loops usually
>   maintain **no explicit counter**: they essentially say "do this to
>   everything in this set", rather than "do this x times". This avoids
>   potential **off-by-one errors** and makes code simpler to read.

So the concept of a foreach loop describes that the loop does not use any explicit counter which means that there is no need of using indexes to traverse in the list thus it saves user from off-by-one error. To describe the general concept of this off-by-one error, let us take an example of a loop to traverse in a list using indexes.

```
// In this loop it is assumed that the list starts with index 0
for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){

}
```

But suppose if the list starts with index 1 then this loop is going to throw an exception as it will found no element at index 0 and this error is called an off-by-one error. So to avoid this off-by-one error the concept of a foreach loop is used. There may be other advantages too, but this is what I think is the main concept and advantage of using a foreach loop.

Comment: How does this answer the question? *"What would the equivalent for loop look like without using the for each syntax?"*

Answer (score 19):

In Java 8, they introduced forEach. Using it List, Maps can be looped.

**Loop a List using for each**

```
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
someList.add("A");
someList.add("B");
someList.add("C");

someList.forEach(listItem -> System.out.println(listItem))
```

or

```
someList.forEach(listItem-> {
     System.out.println(listItem); 
});
```

**Loop a Map using for each**

```
Map<String, String> mapList = new HashMap<>();
    mapList.put("Key1", "Value1");
    mapList.put("Key2", "Value2");
    mapList.put("Key3", "Value3");

mapList.forEach((key,value)->System.out.println("Key: " + key + " Value : " + value));
```

or

```
mapList.forEach((key,value)->{
    System.out.println("Key : " + key + " Value : " + value);
});
```

Answer (score 15):

Here's an equivalent expression.

```
for(Iterator<String> sit = someList.iterator(); sit.hasNext(); ) {
    System.out.println(sit.next());
}
```

Answer (score 15):

An alternative to forEach in order to avoid your "for each":

```java
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Variant 1 (plain):

```java
someList.stream().forEach(listItem -> {
    System.out.println(listItem);
});
```

Variant 2 (parallel execution (faster)):

```java
someList.parallelStream().forEach(listItem -> {
    System.out.println(listItem);
});
```

Comment: Should have mention that it's added in Java 1.8

Comment: We cant be 100% sure that the same thread is used. I like to use the `for(` form if I like to make sure the same thread is used. I like to use the stream-form if I like to allow multithreaded execution.

Answer (score 15):

Using older Java versions, including [Java 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7), you can use a `foreach` loop as follows.

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add("A");
items.add("B");
items.add("C");
items.add("D");
items.add("E");

for(String item : items) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

The following is the very latest way of using a *for each* loop in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) (loop a List with `forEach` + lambda expression or method reference).

#### Lambda

```
// Output: A,B,C,D,E
items.forEach(item->System.out.println(item));
```

#### Method reference

```
// Output: A,B,C,D,E
items.forEach(System.out::println);
```

For more information, refer to *"[Java 8 forEach examples](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-foreach-examples/)"*.

Answer (score 14):

```
for (Iterator<String> itr = someList.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
   String item = itr.next();
   System.out.println(item);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Also note that using the "foreach" method in the original question does have some limitations, such as not being able to remove items from the list during the iteration.

The new for-loop is easier to read and removes the need for a separate iterator, but is only really usable in read-only iteration passes.

Comment: In those cases, the use of `removeIf` might be the right tool

Answer (score 10):

It adds beauty to your code by removing all the basic looping clutter. It gives a clean look to your code, justified below.

**Normal `for` loop:**

```
void cancelAll(Collection<TimerTask> list) {
    for (Iterator<TimerTask> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
         i.next().cancel();
}
```

**Using for-each:**

```
void cancelAll(Collection<TimerTask> list) {
    for (TimerTask t : list)
        t.cancel();
}
```

**for-each** is a construct over a collection that implements **Iterator**. Remember that, your collection should implement **Iterator**; otherwise you can't use it with for-each.

The following line is read as "*for each TimerTask t in list.*"

```
for (TimerTask t : list)
```

There is less chance for errors in case of for-each. You don't have to worry about initializing the iterator or initializing the loop counter and terminating it (where there is scope for errors).

Answer (score 10):

Prior to Java 8, you need to use the following:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = someList.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String item = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

However, with the introduction of Streams in Java 8 you can do same thing in much less syntax. For example, for your `someList` you can do:

```
someList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

You can find more about streams [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

Comment: `The foreach loop, added in Java 5 (also called the "enhanced for loop"), is equivalent to using a java.util.Iterator`

Answer (score 9):

It would look something like this. Very crufty.

```
for (Iterator<String> i = someList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
        System.out.println(i.next());
```

There is a good writeup on *for each* in the [Sun documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Answer (score 9):

As so many good answers said, an object must implement the `Iterable interface` if it wants to use a `for-each` loop.

I'll post a simple example and try to explain in a different way how a `for-each` loop works.

The `for-each` loop example:

```
public class ForEachTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("111");
        list.add("222");

        for (String str : list) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, if we use `javap` to decompile this class, we will get this bytecode sample:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=4, args_size=1
         0: new           #16                 // class java/util/ArrayList
         3: dup
         4: invokespecial #18                 // Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
         7: astore_1
         8: aload_1
         9: ldc           #19                 // String 111
        11: invokeinterface #21,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.add:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
        16: pop
        17: aload_1
        18: ldc           #27                 // String 222
        20: invokeinterface #21,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.add:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
        25: pop
        26: aload_1
        27: invokeinterface #29,  1           // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
```

As we can see from the last line of the sample, the compiler will automatically convert the use of `for-each` keyword to the use of an `Iterator` at compile time. That may explain why object, which doesn't implement the `Iterable interface`, will throw an `Exception` when it tries to use the `for-each` loop.

Answer (score 9):

As many of other answers correctly state, the *for each* loop is just syntactic sugar over the same old *for* loop and the compiler translates it to the same old *for* loop.

javac ([OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK)) has a switch, `-XD-printflat`, which generates a Java file with all the syntactic sugar removed. The complete command looks like this:

```
javac -XD-printflat -d src/ MyFile.java

//-d is used to specify the directory for output java file
```

#### So let’s remove the syntactical sugar

To answer this question, I created a file and wrote two versions of *for each*, one with *array* and another with a *list*. My Java file looked like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Temp{

    private static void forEachArray(){
        int[] arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
        for(int i: arr){
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }

    private static void forEachList(){
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
        for(Integer i: list){
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
}
```

When I `compiled` this file with above switch, I got the following output.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Temp {

    public Temp() {
        super();
    }

    private static void forEachArray() {
        int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        for (/*synthetic*/ int[] arr$ = arr, len$ = arr$.length, i$ = 0; i$ < len$; ++i$) {
            int i = arr$[i$];
            {
                System.out.print(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void forEachList() {
        List list = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(2), Integer.valueOf(3), Integer.valueOf(4), Integer.valueOf(5)});
        for (/*synthetic*/ Iterator i$ = list.iterator(); i$.hasNext(); ) {
            Integer i = (Integer)i$.next();
            {
                System.out.print(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that along with the other syntactic sugar (Autoboxing), *for each* loops got changed to simple loops.

Answer (score 8):

The [Java for each loop](https://funnelgarden.com/java-for-loop/#Enhanced_For_Loop) (aka enhanced for loop) is a simplified version of a for loop. The advantage is that there is less code to write and less variables to manage. The downside is that you have no control over the step value and no access to the loop index inside the loop body.

They are best used when the step value is a simple increment of 1 and when you only need access to the current loop element. For example, if you need to loop over every element in an array or Collection without peeking ahead or behind the current element.

There is no loop initialization, no boolean condition and the step value is implicit and is a simple increment. This is why they are considered so much simpler than regular for loops.

Enhanced for loops follow this order of execution:

1) loop body

2) repeat from step 1 until entire array or collection has been traversed

**Example – Integer Array**

```
int [] intArray = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
for(int currentValue : intArray) {
  System.out.println(currentValue);
}
```

The currentValue variable holds the current value being looped over in the intArray array. Notice there’s no explicit step value – it’s always an increment by 1.

The colon can be thought of to mean “in”. So the enhanced for loop declaration states: loop over intArray and store the current array int value **in** the currentValue variable.

Output:

```
1
3
5
7
9
```

**Example – String Array**

We can use the for-each loop to iterate over an array of strings. The loop declaration states: loop over myStrings String array and store the current String value **in** the currentString variable.

```
String [] myStrings  = {
  "alpha",
  "beta",
  "gamma",
  "delta"
};

for(String currentString : myStrings) {
  System.out.println(currentString);
}
```

Output:

```
alpha
beta
gamma
delta
```

**Example – List**

The enhanced for loop can also be used to iterate over a java.util.List as follows:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("alpha");
myList.add("beta");
myList.add("gamma");
myList.add("delta");

for(String currentItem : myList) {
  System.out.println(currentItem);
}
```

The loop declaration states: loop over myList List of Strings and store the current List value **in** the currentItem variable.

Output:

```
alpha
beta
gamma
delta
```

**Example – Set**

The enhanced for loop can also be used to iterate over a java.util.Set as follows:

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();
mySet.add("alpha");
mySet.add("alpha");
mySet.add("beta");
mySet.add("gamma");
mySet.add("gamma");
mySet.add("delta");

for(String currentItem : mySet) {
  System.out.println(currentItem);
}
```

The loop declaration states: loop over mySet Set of Strings and store the current Set value **in** the currentItem variable. Notice that since this is a Set, duplicate String values are not stored.

Output:

```
alpha
delta
beta
gamma
```

Source: [Loops in Java – Ultimate Guide](https://funnelgarden.com/java-for-loop/)

Answer (score 6):

```
public static Boolean Add_Tag(int totalsize)
{
    List<String> fullst = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int k=0; k<totalsize; k++)
    {
        fullst.addAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think we need this answer. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work/59667941#comment121529936_66815146).

Answer (score 5):

The Java for-each idiom can only be applied to arrays or objects of type ***Iterable**. This idiom is ***implicit*** as it truly backed by an Iterator. The Iterator is programmed by the programmer and often uses an integer index or a node (depending on the data structure) to keep track of its position. On paper it is slower than a regular for-loop, a least for "linear" structures like arrays and Lists but it provides greater abstraction.

Comment: -1: this is way less readable (generally): even your own example (the first one) is wrong, as it leaves out the first element in the array.

Answer (score 2):

This looks crazy but hey it works

```
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<>(); //has content
someList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This works. ***Magic***

Comment: This requires Java 1.8 +

Comment: doesn't even remotely answer the question

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:

```
for (Iterator<String> i = someList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
   String x = i.next();
   System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: Please explain why your code and try to answer the question "How does the Java 'for each' loop work?"

Answer (score 2):

The code would be:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ForLoopDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();

    someList.add("monkey");
    someList.add("donkey");
    someList.add("skeleton key");

    // Iteration using For Each loop
    System.out.println("Iteration using a For Each loop:");
    for (String item : someList) {
      System.out.println(item);
    }

    // Iteration using a normal For loop
    System.out.println("\nIteration using normal For loop: ");
    for (int index = 0; index < someList.size(); index++) {
      System.out.println(someList.get(index));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) This is incorrect.  The direct equivalent to a for-each on an iterable (such as a list) uses an iterator.  That's what the JLS says.  Look it up. 2) We don't need more answers to this question.  Please don't waste everyone's time by adding yet another answer to old questions.  Find new questions that you can answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using *forEach*:

```java
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5};

Arrays.stream(numbers).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Response:

```
1
2
3
4
5

The process finished with exit code 0
```

PS: You need a Array (`int[] numbers`), and `import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).